# У тега нет дочерних элементов. Почему список по которому доступны дочерние элементы .contents (BS4) не возвращает []?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Дочерних элементов у тега нету, но `.contents` возвращает список из 1 элемента (строка с 1 пробелом).[image: HTML]

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
soup_tag = soup.find('div', class_='grid-container')
print(soup_tag.contents)
```

[' ']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере класс:

```html
<div class="grid-container"> </div>
```

Возвращает пробел из-за того, что в нём есть отступ, длиной в один пробел.

При попытке вывода `<div>` с дочерними элементами, `BeautifulSoup` [выведет](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) всё, что в нём находится, а параметр `.contents` выведет массив значения, который вложен между `<div> </div>`.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение.  Мне нужно было узнать наличие дочерних элементов. Сразу не додумался:  надо было просто использовать soup_tag.find()